# Bootstrap 3 radio button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm playing with twitter bootstrap 3 and its new [radio buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) and cannot seem to get which button is checked.

My buttons are like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputLogType" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Log type</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="inputLogType" id="splunk">Splunk
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="inputLogType" id="pig">PIG
          </label>
        </div>          
      </div>            
    </div>
```

I can get whether either button is clicked through `$(".btn-group").click()`, but inside there I can't get which button is clicked. I'll get the 2 buttons through jquery `$("input[name='inputLogType']")`, and one of them will have `checked:true` property. However when I do `$("input[name='inputLogType']:checked")`, nothing shows up.

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: so turned out if I do `$("input[name='inputLogType']")[i].checked` it worked, but does anyone know why I can't select like I showed above initially?

Comment: Are you trying to access the `:checked` value in the click callback? If so, it's likely that the property hasn't been applied yet.

You could use `$(event.target).find('input');`

Comment: That selector worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/QMsQU/1/ (using chrome). What javascript were you using to show what was inside the $("input[name='inputLogType']:checked") jQuery object?

Comment: @Joe_G I was just using `console.log`. Weird thing is it worked in jsfiddle but not in my app. Do you think this might have something to do with bootstrap 3?

Comment: Hmm turned out in my script it was only showing the last clicked one - so if I click "pig" the first time, it selected nothing, and when I click "splunk", it showed pig is selected, and so forth. Any idea why :S?

Comment: sorry for spamming but @BenjaminCorey could you post it as an answer? thank you!

Comment: What you guys aren't noticing is that Bootstrap is not using the default "checked" property on the radio button, it adds the class "active" to the label containing the radio button when it's clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to access the `:checked` value in the click callback? If so, it's likely that the property hasn't been applied yet.

You can use `$(event.target).find('input');` to select the targeted radio button.

Comment: I had to use $(event.target).find('input')[0]; to get the DOM element (rather than the jQuery element).